# TeamCity Missing Items in Work Directory Checkouts

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, build-process, build-automation

I've been pouring over my set up for what feels like most of the day and I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have 3 build configurations running on a single agent on my dev box.  Checking out code from SVN.

I've got OctPack installed to create a couple of packages for deployment.  In addition to this I've created a nuspec file to use in a NuGet Pack step.  All of these bits work fine when testing.

The problem is that the nuspec file packages up some sql script files for deployment.  Nothing fancy.

The problem is these sql files are disappearing from disk in the work folder.  I get:

`Cannot start build runner: Failed to find files to create packages matching: [src\database\SqlScriptsPackage.nuspec] under H:\TeamCity-Build\work\a1dbf81458fbab0a.`

The entire database directory is empty despite all the contents being in SVN.

I've tried everything I can think of, including a forcing a clean checkout.

All the projects are using the same VCS Root setup to checkout "Automatically on server".

What could be ditching all these files?

Comment: Do you use checkout rules?
Try to disable all build steps and add just one with Command Line Runner that will list `database` directory and see, if files are there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Disable the `[] Clean output directory` checkbox on the `NuGet Pack` step.

I had this issue where I set the target directory for the Nuget pack step to be the same folder as the `.csproj` file I was building from.

With the tickbox ticked, it wiped the entire directory immediatly after checking it out.

Comment: I had a similar situation, and found out that the path to csproj file was wrong. After fixing the path, the nuget pack worked perfectly although the tickbox for cleaning the output directory was ticked.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error when running on TeamCity:

> Failed to find files to create packages matching: [myProject/myProject.nuspec]
>   under {C:\TeamCity\work\XXXXXXXXXX}

The key for us was that reading this message you could interpret it as it cannot find the files to go in the nuget package.

**However, the issue was that it cannot find the .nuspec file**.

So this then helped us look at the TeamCity working directory and what we were missing to get to the 'myProject' .nuspec path above.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the reply, I'll take a look as I ended up going a different route in the end.

Answer (score 1):

Another thing to check is that you have the Octopack nuget package installed in your Visual Studio project. I forgot to do this with one of my projects and received the "Failed to find files to create packages matching" error. More information is available here:

http://help.octopusdeploy.com/discussions/questions/2304-teamcity-804-not-creating-nuget-packages